# show the inner product of a matrix form a positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose D is some $n\times n$ matrix and we want to show $D^TD$ is positive definite.

I know that all the diagonal entries of $D^TD$ are non-negative, but then should I show the eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: By non-negative definite you mean positive semi-definite?  Use the definition.

Comment: The title is not in agreement with the body.

Comment: @hardmath, I think I want it to be positive definite.

Comment: That would not be true in general (e.g. consider $D$ zero, or more generally singular).